# How do you allow the user to add items to a tableview in iPhone SDK?

Tags: uitableview, user-interface, uikit, addition, tableview

I'm kind of new to this stuff. I was wondering how you can allow the user of your iPhone app to add new items to your tableview. If you're confused by what I mean, please look at the free app, ListGnome.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at apples sample code, recipe shows you how to add new items.